# Remove NA rows based on mulitple columns's name in R

Tags: r

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
A   B   C
1   2   NA
NA  2   3
1   NA  3
1   2   3
```

How could I remove rows based on the condition: columns `B` and `C` have `NA`s?

The expected result will like this:

```
A   B   C
NA  2   3
1   2   3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option in Base R is

```
df[complete.cases(df[c("B","C")]),]

   A B C
2 NA 2 3
4  1 2 3
```

Comment: `na.omit(df, cols = c("B", "C"))` seems also works.

Answer (score 2):

With `base R`:

```r
df[!is.na(df$B) & !is.na(df$C),]
```

Using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(B), !is.na(C))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     2     3
2     1     2     3
```

or

```r
df %>%
  drop_na(B, C)
```